# Wygwam: Can I create custom link_type with editable URL?

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam, wysiwyg

I'm trying to [create a custom link type in Wygwam (using the wygwam_config extension hook)](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/developers/link_types.html): I want the user to be able to specify a URL (like the normal URL link type), but I want to specify a CSS class that is predefined and not editable.

The Wygwam docs only describe to create links with predefined URLs (i.e. Wygwam auto-generates a dropdown menu of possible pages for each link type). Is there a way I can force a CSS class but leave the URL editable in the dialog box?

Comment: Will this be for all links inside your article or do you have a mix of link types?

Comment: The end goal is to be able to represent any link as either a normal link or as a styled "button" link (<a>, not <button>). So, multiple link types.

Comment: Michael, are you hoping for this to be an additional toolbar item?

Comment: I was hoping to implement it as a custom link type, since writing a CKEditor plugin seems slightly more involved... but I'd be happy with an additional toolbar button, yes.

Comment: Have you thought about just adding another "Style" to be used? You can set that up fairly easily. Might not be the best case scenario but should get the job done: http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/using/style_set.html

Comment: Yes, but the custom style set doesn't seem to like the <a> element.